# The centroid of a list of points

Tags: list, haskell, syntax, function-call, centroid

New to Haskell

The problem is

> ```
> -- The centroid of a list of points is a point whose x (and y) coordinates are
> -- the means of the x (and y) coordinates of the points in the list.
> --
> -- You may assume the list contains at least one point.
> --
> -- > centroid [Pt 1 1, Pt 2 2]
> -- Pt 1.5 1.5
> -- > centroid [Pt (-1.5) 0, Pt 3 2, Pt 0 1]
> -- Pt 0.5 1.0
> ```

Try to code like this

```
data Point = Pt Double Double deriving (Show, Eq)

centroid :: [Point] -> Point

pointX :: Point -> Double
pointX (Pt x y) = x
pointY :: Point -> Double
pointY (Pt x y) = y

pointsX :: [Point] -> [Double]
pointsX xs = map pointX xs
pointsY :: [Point] -> [Double]
pointsY xs = map pointY xs

average :: [Double] -> Double
average xs = (sum xs) `div` (genericLength xs)

centroid cenpoint = (Pt average(pointsX cenpoint) average(pointsY cenpoint))
```

And I got

```
Project1.hs:35:22: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘([Double] -> Double)
                                    -> [Double] -> Point’
                  with actual type ‘Point’
    • The function ‘Pt’ is applied to four arguments,
      but its type ‘Double -> Double -> Point’ has only two
      In the expression:
        (Pt average (pointsX cenpoint) average (pointsY cenpoint))
      In an equation for ‘centroid’:
          centroid cenpoint
            = (Pt average (pointsX cenpoint) average (pointsY cenpoint))
   |
35 | centroid cenpoint = (Pt average(pointsX cenpoint) average(pointsY cenpoint))
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Project1.hs:35:25: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’
                  with actual type ‘[Double] -> Double’
    • Probable cause: ‘average’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of ‘Pt’, namely ‘average’
      In the expression:
        (Pt average (pointsX cenpoint) average (pointsY cenpoint))
      In an equation for ‘centroid’:
          centroid cenpoint
            = (Pt average (pointsX cenpoint) average (pointsY cenpoint))
   |
35 | centroid cenpoint = (Pt average(pointsX cenpoint) average(pointsY cenpoint))
   |                         ^^^^^^^

Project1.hs:35:33: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘[Double]’
    • In the second argument of ‘Pt’, namely ‘(pointsX cenpoint)’
      In the expression:
        (Pt average (pointsX cenpoint) average (pointsY cenpoint))
      In an equation for ‘centroid’:
          centroid cenpoint
            = (Pt average (pointsX cenpoint) average (pointsY cenpoint))
   |
35 | centroid cenpoint = (Pt average(pointsX cenpoint) average(pointsY cenpoint))
   |
```

Comment: FYI, with record syntax, `data Point = Pt { pointX, pointY :: Double } deriving (Show, Eq)`, you get the two functions `pointX`, `pointY` for free.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem here is that you call the functions, like you would do in a language like Java, C++, or Python.

You need to wrap `average` into parenthesis, like:

```
centroid cenpoint = Pt (average (pointsX cenpoint)) (average (pointsY cenpoint))
```

As [@dfeuer says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347892/the-centroid-of-a-list-of-points/58347949?noredirect=1#comment103051080_58347949), the outer parenthesis are not necessary here.

Furthermore you probably want to use `(/)` here over `div`, since you are working with `Double`s, whereas `div` works on `Integral` types:

```
average :: [Double] -> Double
average xs = sum xs / genericLength xs
```

but like [@leftroundabout says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347892/the-centroid-of-a-list-of-points/58347949?noredirect=1#comment103053818_58347949), we can better use `length`, and then use `fromIntegral`:

```
average :: [Double] -> Double
average xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the outermost parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: `genericLength` is controversial. I'd just use `fromIntegral (length xs)`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout why is `genericLength` controversial? I thought it was identical to `fromIntegral . length`, that is a version of `length` with a polymorphic return value (which really should have been used in the Prelude instead of the monomorphic `length` that's actually there).

Comment: @RobinZigmond: I think because for a `Double` there are (large) values, for which `x + 1.0 == x`, since the mantissa can no has the "resolution" to increment with one. This thus means that for large lists, the `genericLength`, will "stop counting" at a given length.

Comment: @RobinZigmond yeah, that about `x + 1 ≡ x` is one concrete problem with floats in particular – but in case of `Double` it would only be an issue for _gargantuan_ lists. But more generally, it just doesn't make sense to carry out lots of additions in a custom number type, when `Int` is basically _always_ the sweet spot of sufficient size and guaranteed good performance. With `genericLength` it can easily happen that you do lots of additions in a really inefficient type, instead of doing them all in `Int` and only converting the result in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, I looked up the implementation and can see what you mean. Which of course begs the question of why it wasn't defined as `fromIntegral . length`.

Comment: Nevermind, that's obvious when I think about it, it wouldn't work if the aim is to get an `Integer` or some other value whose bounds are less restrictive than those of `Int`

Answer (score 3):

You were doing pretty well - note how the compilation errors all point to your final line (the definition of `centroid`). And they're all due to incorrect bracketing. This is what it should be instead:

```
centroid cenpoint = Pt (average (pointsX cenpoint)) (average (pointsY cenpoint))
```

That is, the x co-ordinate of the resulting `Pt` value is the average of the x co-ordinates of the corresponding points (`pointsX cenpoint` is the list of x-coordinates, so `average (pointsX cenpoint)` is their average), and similarly for the y co-ordinate.

Comparing to your incorrect version (which I have tidied up a little without changing how it is interpreted by the compiler):

```
Pt average (pointsX cenpoint) average (pointsY cenpoint)
```

This means you apply the `Pt` function to 4 arguments: `average`, `pointsX cenpoint`, `average` again, and `pointsY cenpoint`. This simply doesn't work because the `Pt` function only takes 2 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to the question, but – this is the preferred way of doing it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}

import Data.VectorSpace
import GHC.Generics

data Point = Pt Double Double
   deriving (Eq, Show, Generic, AdditiveGroup, VectorSpace)

average :: (VectorSpace v, Fractional (Scalar v)) => [v] -> v
average ps = sumV ps ^/ fromIntegral (length xs)
```

Then you can directly do

```
> average [Pt (-1.5) 0, Pt 3 2, Pt 0 1]
Pt 0.5 1.0
```

I.e. `centroid ≡ average`.